# ui:repeat var attribute not working as expected

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

Due to the [problem with @ViewScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039065/use-of-jstl-core-tags-screws-up-viewscoped-bean), I have to use ui:repeat instead of c:foreach in my facelet.  However I encounter this problem and I wonder if anyone can suggest a work-around.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{someBean.idCodes}"
           var="led">
           <h:outputText id="mailbox-#{led}" 
               value="#{someBean.getSomeValue(led)}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

The first problem is that the #{led} reference is the id attribute does NOT get evaluated.  All the generated id attributes are simply the value "mailbox-".  I need to find specific element instances with document.getElementById() so I need generated id attributes.

The other problem which I can't see a workaround for is that if I wrap the ui:repeat element inside an h:panelGrid element, I end up with a table with one cell in it, rather than one cell for each member of the idCodes collection.

When using c:foreach neither of these problems exist, but use of that tag causes other problems.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice in the [javadocs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html) that the type of the id attribute is String, not ValueExpression.  That's why your ${led} is not evaluated.  You could try to wrap each one in a div or span and set the id of that element to your ${led} based expression.

Comment: Debbil in the details.  Your suggestion worked.  Interesting though why it would work with c:foreach.  I haven't looked into the implementation but it suggests that there is a different pass to process JSTL tags that follows different rules.

Comment: this blog post http://www.ilikespam.com/jsf/c%3Aforeach-vs-ui%3Arepeat-in-facelets explains how the jstl tags are processed differently than the native JSF tags and why mixing the two is a bad idea.  It's an excellent read that every JSF programmer should read.