# JSF ui:repeat included by ui:include wrapped in h:panelGroup with conditional rendering... A mouthfull

Tags: jsf, include, conditional-statements, uirepeat

Original question is below, but as I have come up with a more minimal example to demonstrate this problem, and figured it should go at the top.

Anyway, it appears that `ui:repeat` tags are processed before checking to see if parent elements are actually rendered.  To recreate this, here is the facelet (minimalTest.xhtml):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
  <title>Test JSF &lt;ui:repeat&gt; inside &lt;h:panelGroup rendered=&quot;false&quot;&gt;</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <h1>Testing</h1>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="false">
      <span>#{minimalTestBean.alsoThrowsException}</span>
      <ul>
        <ui:repeat value="#{minimalTestBean.throwsException}" var="item">
          <li>#{item}</li>
        </ui:repeat>
      </ul>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

With using this bean (MinimalTestBean.java):

```
package com.lucastheisen.beans;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MinimalTestBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9045030165653014015L;

    public String getAlsoThrowsException() {
        throw new RuntimeException( "rendered is false so this shouldnt get called either" );
    }

    public List<String> getThrowsException() {
        throw new RuntimeException( "rendered is false so this shouldnt get called" );
    }
}
```

From this example you can see that the `h:panelGroup` that contains the `ui:repeat` is statically set to `rendered=false` which I would assume would mean that none of the EL expressions inside of that `h:panelGroup` would get executed.  The EL expressions just call getters which throw a RuntimeException.  However, the `ui:repeat` is actually calling the getter for its list thus causing the exception even though it should not be getting rendered in the first place.  If you comment out the `ui:repeat` element, no exceptions get thrown (even though the other EL expression remains in the `h:panelGroup`) as I would expect.

Reading other questions here on stackoverflow leads me to believe that is likely related to the oft-referred-to [chicken/egg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039065/use-of-jstl-core-tags-screws-up-viewscoped-bean/6039193#6039193) issue, but I am not sure exactly why, nor what to do about it.  I imagine setting the PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false might help, but would like to avoid the memory implications.

---- ORIGINAL QUESTION ----

Basically, I have a page that conditionally renders sections using `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{modeXXX}">` wrapped around `<ui:include src="pageXXX.xhtml" />` (per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449873/viewscoped-bean-getting-constructed-on-every-request-part-99/7450195#7450195)).  The problem is that if one of the pageXXX.xhtml has a `<ui:repeat>` inside of it, it seems to get processed even when the containing `<h:panelGroup>` has `rendered=false`.  This is a problem because some of my sections rely on having been initialized by other sections that should be visited before them.  Why is the included pageXXX.xhtml getting processed?

This is a painful bug and incredibly hard to boil down to a small example, but here is the most minimal case I could build that demonstrates the issue.  First a base page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
  <title>Test JSF &lt;ui:include&gt;</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <h1>#{testBean.title}</h1>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{testBean.modeOne}">
      <ui:include src="modeOne.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{testBean.modeTwo}">
      <ui:include src="modeTwo.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

As you can see this page will conditionally include either the modeOne page or the modeTwo page based upon the value in the testBean bean.  Then you have modeOne (the default):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<ui:composition>
  <span>Okay, I&apos;m ready.  Take me to </span>
  <h:commandLink action="#{testBean.setModeTwo}">mode two.</h:commandLink>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Which in my real world app would be a page that sets up things needed by modeTwo.  Once set up, an action on this page will direct you to modeTwo:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <ui:composition>
    <div>Here is your list:</div>
    <ui:repeat value="#{testBeanToo.list}" var="item">
      <div>#{item}</div>
    </ui:repeat>
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

The modeTwo page basically presents a details for the modeOne page in a ui:repeat as the actual information is in a collection.  The main managed bean (TestBean):

```
package test.lucastheisen.beans;


import java.io.Serializable;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6542086191355916513L;
    private Mode mode;
    @ManagedProperty( value="#{testBeanToo}" )
    private TestBeanToo testBeanToo;

    public TestBean() {
        System.out.println( "constructing TestBean" );
        setModeOne();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        System.out.println( "\ttb.getTitle()" );
        return mode.getTitle();
    }

    public boolean isModeOne() {
        return mode == Mode.One;
    }

    public boolean isModeTwo() {
        return mode == Mode.Two;
    }

    public void setModeOne() {
        this.mode = Mode.One;
    }

    public void setModeTwo() {
        testBeanToo.getReadyCauseHereICome();
        this.mode = Mode.Two;
    }

    public void setTestBeanToo( TestBeanToo testBeanToo ) {
        this.testBeanToo = testBeanToo;
    }

    private enum Mode {
        One("Mode One"),
        Two("Mode Two");

        private String title;

        private Mode( String title ) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the bean for all the main data, and the TestBeanToo bean would be for the details:

```
package test.lucastheisen.beans;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBeanToo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6542086191355916513L;
    private ObjectWithList objectWithList = null;

    public TestBeanToo() {
        System.out.println( "constructing TestBeanToo" );
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        System.out.println( "\ttb2.getTitle()" );
        return "Test Too";
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        System.out.println( "\ttb2.getList()" );
        return objectWithList.getList();
    }

    public void getReadyCauseHereICome() {
        System.out.println( "\ttb2.getList()" );
        objectWithList = new ObjectWithList();
    }

    public class ObjectWithList {
        private List<String> list;

        public ObjectWithList() {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add( "List item 1" );
            list.add( "List item 2" );
        }

        public List<String> getList() {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ui:repeat>` does not check the `rendered` attribute of itself (it has actually none) and its parents when the view is to be rendered. Consider using [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/index.html) [`<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) instead.

Comment: That is what I was beginning to think.  Thanks for the verification.  This does feel like a JSF bug as there is no way to stop a `ui:repeat` from processing.  In my case the page before is what initializes the underlying object referred to by the repeat so I cannot use it.  I will look into tomahawk, but am currently testing a custom component (extending from UIComponentBase).